# Can I save ImageIcon with ObjectOutputStream?

Tags: java, imageicon, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

Does anybody know if you can save an `ImageIcon` file with `ObjectOutputStream`?
I have a person-registry that I save with an `ObjectOutputStream`, So it would be really convenient to to write the the `imageicon` together with that information.
But when I try to read the image icon, nothing happens. I get to read all the other information but cant seem to get the `ImageIcon`.

Anybody got any ideas to what I can do?

EDIT:
I have a person class and a person registry class. 
below is the person class and the personregistry class is just a collection of several persons. i write out the person-registry with objectoutput stream.

```
public Person(String fn, String en, String a, int t, ImageIcon kb, Kort k)   {
        fname= fn;
        lname= en;
        adress= a;
        tlf= t;
        card= k;
        df.format(medlemsNr= ++nextNr);
        cardPicture= kb;
        neste= null;
    }

public void writePersonsToFile()   {
        try(ObjectOutputStream utfil= new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(("PersonRegistry.data"))))   {
            utfil.writeObject(personRegistry);
        }
        catch(NotSerializableException nse) {

        }
        catch(IOException ioe)  {

        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you read the `imageicon` with `ObjectInputStream` ?

Comment: Well, nothing. First I read the person-registry with succes. All the data (text) is there, but the imageicon I want it to display on a JLabel with JLabel.setIcon(imageIcon), but nothing happens.

Comment: Can you share the code where you are saving `imageicon` with `ObjectOutputStream` and the code where you are reading `imageicon`

Comment: posted code. And i use the same method when I read. 
InputObjectStream 
personRegistry= (Personregistry) inFile.readObject();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it at last. It was a stupid mistake on my hand. 
It worked fine to save the `ImageIcon` through `ObjectOutputStream` and in again.
The trouble was with the file I tried to save.

The `ImageIcon` that I wanted to save was inside a `JLabel` on the GUI.
To save it, I had to get the Icon first with:

```
ImageIcon imgIcon= (ImageIcon)imgLabel.getIcon();
```

and then run it through the outputstream. Thanks for all help. =)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question? You have a stream of image and you want to create a imageicon object to draw or other action?

If this, you can using `ImageIO.read(ImageInputStream stream)`in [ImageIO class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream%29)

If you have a stream of image (ex: from url) and want to save to image file, you can save to file by wrap it with `FileOutputStream` and simple write it to a file.

Comment: The thing is I have a ImageIcon and I want to save it together with String information (if this is possible) in an objectoutputstream and then read it in again from an objectinputstream. Or do I have to save the imageicon seperately in an ImageOutput?